# Trying to implement butterworth for high and low pass filter on data but am getting errors

Tags: matlab, user-interface, filter, filtering

I am trying to create a GUI. within this GUI I have a popup menu to choose the type of filter to be applied and a listbox for the user to select the cutoff frequency. The data was recorded at 500 samples per second and is currently in an [1,800,000x1 single]

My code currently looks like this:

```
%get cutoff frequency from listbox
contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String'));
cutoff_frequency=contents{get(hObject,'Value')};

data=handles.data1;
sampling_rate=500;
handles.sampling_rate=sampling_rate;
Wn=cutoff_frequency/(sampling_rate/2);
filter=handles.filter;

if filter=='High Pass'
  [B,A]=butter(2,Wn,'high')
  data=filter(B,A,data);
  figure
  plot(data);

end
```

**Errors:**

I am getting the error: "For the 'high' filter option, Wn must be a 1 element vector"
**FIXED** by converting cutoff_frequency from a string to a number

```
cutoff_frequency=str2num(cutoff_frequency)
```

I also received this error when I removed 'high' from the butter function and fixed the first error: "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

I need help applying a high and low pass filter to the data.

If somebody could also tell me how to determine what order filter should be used that would be great

Comment: If you look at the type of `cutoff_frequency` in the variable list, what does it say?

Comment: I coded: 'class (cutoff_frequency)' and it came back as a character. the GUI doesn't keep variables in the workspace. If that's not what you needed let me know.

Comment: in the handle structure it gives `cutoff_frequency: '1'` or whatever number I select in the listbox

Comment: So the problem is that `Wn` is not a number because you're dividing a character by a number. You need to convert `cutoff_frequency` into a number, then you might solve the first error

Comment: thanks, I just coded `cutoff_frequency=str2num(cutoff_frequency)` and it did fix the first error. It's giving me the second error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix

MATlab didn't like me using filter as a variable when I use it as a function later in the code.
by changing my filter variable to filter_choice everything runs smoothly.